# Calculate the Z of a line intersection given the XY coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, intersection

I'm intersecting a line in 2D and I calculate the X,Y coordinates of the intersection point. What I need is the Z of the intersection point given the X,Y,Z of the line points, and the X,Y of the intersection. From what I understand of equations it should be a one-liner but I don't know enough math to get there.

Comment: @Andrey - Its a 3D line with 2 point coordinates in X,Y,Z. The intersection point is somewhere on the line, and known in X,Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, but I will try to answer.

So take following equation:

[image: 3d line equation]

Let's note it as `Fx(X) = Fy(Y) = Fz(Z)` and take a part of it:

- `Fx(X) = Fz(Z)`

Then you said you know x, y and z for two points, put it to x1, x2, z1, z2 accordingly. Then put x of intersection to x. Now you have a linear equation with one variable z. Here it is:

```
z = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) * (z2 - z1) + z1
```

Comment: sorry but I'm no math guy. I just started off developing software from the logic POV. Can you write that in a simpler equation form that I could key into my program?